# Swift 3 Gestures + TouchesBegan BUG?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I am using xcode 8.0 & Swift 3.

**Here's the overview of my issue:**

- Scrollview with an imageview named "insidepic" as a subview.
- a duplicate of the imageview named "outsidepic" is positioned outside the scrollview.
- When "outsidepic" is tapped, touchesBegan is fired.
- When "insidepic" is tapped, the tap gesture is fired...but not touchesBegan or touchesEnded are fired.

**Here's what I need to solve:**

I need for touchesBegan to get fired when the scrollview is tapped. I have added the ".cancelsTouchesInView = false" to the gesture.

Furthermore, the zoom/pan gesturing on the scrollview needs to stay intact. So userinteraction is enabled on both the scrollview & the imageview inside.

This [see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOQiF.png) shows the layout & the viewcontroller swift file.
The yellow area is the scrollview. (with "insidepic" inside)

But, for quick reference, here is my code:

```
import UIKit
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var insidepic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var outsidepic: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scroller.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scroller.maximumZoomScale = 6
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        tap.delegate = self
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        scroller.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touches Began")
    }

    func handleTap(){
        print("Tap Gesture Received")
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return insidepic
    }
}
```

**MANY THANKS FOR ANY HELP OR INSIGHT YOU CAN OFFER!!**

Comment: It's not a bug, but trying to mix gesture recognizers with pure low-level `touches` methods can be very confusing and is not a good idea. Please consider going for a pure gesture recognizer approach.

Comment: I would suggest to add gesture recognize for both insidepic and outsidepic

Comment: @matt - good advice - however, the "insidepic" imageview ultimately will allow the user to draw paths on top of it by drawing & connecting dots...so the other low-level touch events are also important. Do you think gesture recognizers are detailed enough to allow for adding dots, dragging dots, and tracking a loop like touchesmoved offers? (Pardon my ignorance)

Comment: @Vyacheslav I will try that right now... shouldn't they fire through the subview stack already?

Comment: @peytofu ,just check. I do not know workflow of your application

Comment: @Vyacheslav Unfortunately, I did a custom recognizer for each...but adding the 'tap' recognizer to "insidepic" didn't change anything. However, "outsidepic" now acknowledges both the tap & the touch as expected...whereas before it only saw the touch. (because it wasn't in the scroller with the recognizer)

Comment: "however, the `insidepic` imageview ultimately will allow the user to draw paths on top of it by drawing & connecting dots...so the other low-level touch events are also important" Okay, that's fair enough. But then you will have to learn how to mediate between gesture recognizers and touch events. If a gesture recognizer recognizes, all other touch delivery, by default, stops.

Comment: @matt Is that the case even though I set ".cancelsTouchesInView = false"? I was under the impression that this would give me a vehicle to make it work...that's why I kinda thought it was a bug.

Comment: But perhaps you're setting `cancelsTouchesInView` on the wrong gesture recognizer. It seems to me that you need to be dealing with the _scroll view's_ gesture recognizers, through which all this is passing initially. Of course I could be wrong, but after all, you yourself have done a rather brilliant experiment which seems to prove that it is the scroll view itself that makes the difference!

Comment: @matt thanks for the kind words. I am going to try to rework the app using gestures only & see what i can do. Thanks again.

Comment: @matt That worked. I just rebuilt using Gestures instead of touch events & all seems to be better. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll flag. Many thanks!

Comment: @peytofu I yield to you on this one: if you answer your own question (perfectly legal and encouraged) I'll upvote your answer! Delighted to hear you got this worked out.